# setting class based on observable route.events

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

(angular 7)
I'm having some trouble with setting side nav menu options as active after a redirect occurs. It works fine all other times. I have a side nav that has its active class set based on a field called activeRoute

**sidebar html**

```
   <mat-list-item *ngFor="let menuItem of sidebarMenu" class="menu-item" 
   [ngClass]="{'menu-item-active': activeRoute === menuItem.route}" 
   (click)="openPage(menuItem.route)">
   <h4 mat-line>{{menuItem.label}}</h4>
   </mat-list-item>
```

Here is my sidenav component, note I previously was using event.url instead of event.urlAfterRedirects, but it was not console logging the correct value after redirect, until I discovered the later.

**Sidebar component**

```
ngOnInit() {
this.route.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd ) {
    this.activeRoute = event.urlAfterRedirects;    
  }
});
}
```

I tried running manual change detection using

```
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
```

But I would get the following error

```
Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges
```

Setting the active route works under normal navigation, however when I implement authentication, which redirects the user from the /callback route to the requested route, it does not add the active class, presumably because of the value its tried to read is an observable. I do not quite know how I should go about correcting this, either reading the url in another way or is there a way to update classes asynchronously as the result is returned.

Answer (score 0):

use RxJS operators instead of casual conditions, and stop listening to routing events when you destroy your component :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.eventsObs = this.route.events
    .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
    .subscribe(event => this.activeRoute = event.urlAfterRedirects);
}

ngOnDestroy() { this.eventsObs.unsubscribe(); }
```

If you want more information, consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your issue. I will explain you what is the best way to manage this kind of use-case.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I wasn't quite able to get this working as it says urlAfterRedirects does not exist on type Event, I'm sure i've missed a step ? I do take your point on stop listening on destory.

Comment: Well using the URL to test for active menus isn't the best option. You shouldn't do that anyway. Instead you should rely on data inside your routes ou simplify your menu and use routerLinkActive.

Comment: thanks I did get your code working by adding the type event: NavigationEnd after subscribe. But it leaves me in the same place, where it doesn't work after a redirect. I'll look into routerLinkActive